# Sublime Text 3 won't recognize my python installation in another drive

Tags: sublimetext3

I've installed Python 3.7.2 in D: drive (set apart for programs). After installing the portable version of Sublime Text, it won't recognize my Python installation, and when I run a Python program it comes up with the following error: (BTW, I have tried other methods that were suggested in other questions, but it still won't recognize my installation for running. I can still edit code, but not run it).

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts\GameIdea.py"]
[dir: D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts]
[path: c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\icls\;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\icls\;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\windows\system32\openssh\;c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\dal;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\dal;c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\ipt;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\ipt;%systemroot%\system32;%systemroot%;%systemroot%\system32\wbem;%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\system32\openssh\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Arnold\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sublime does not look for external programs when it tries to run them; it just tells the underlying operating system "run this program". The error message you're seeing is a Windows error message telling you that you told it to execute something but it doesn't know what it is.

Breaking down what you see in the build output panel:

> ```
> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
> ```

This is Windows telling you "you tried to run a program called `python`, but I don't know what that program is. It does not appear to be an internal program that I'm aware of, nor does it appear to be a known external program.

> ```
> [shell_cmd: python -u "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts\GameIdea.py"]
> [dir: D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts]
> ```

This is a Sublime diagnostic telling you exactly what command Sublime tried to execute as well as was directory was the "current" directory at the time.

> [path: c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\icls\;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\icls\;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\windows\system32\openssh\;c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\dal;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\dal;c:\program files (x86)\intel\intel(r) management engine components\ipt;c:\program files\intel\intel(r) management engine components\ipt;%systemroot%\system32;%systemroot%;%systemroot%\system32\wbem;%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\system32\openssh\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Arnold\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]

This is the operating system (in this case Windows) list of places where it knows to look for programs, which is the "external command" that the error message is referring to. Looking closely, none of these locations appears to be on drive `D:` or mentions `Python` at all.

As such, when Sublime tells Windows that it needs to run `python`, Windows can't find it because nothing named `python` appears anywhere within any of the folders listed here.

The solution to the problem is to ensure that the system `PATH` includes the location where the `Python` interpreter is located. How you do that depends on the operating system you use, and in the case of Windows may also be slightly different depending on the version of Windows that you're running.

Generally speaking, in order for an external command to work in Sublime, you need to be able to open a command prompt, terminal etc and enter that command and have it work; if that doesn't run the program, Sublime won't be able to run it either.

Comment: Managed to patch this together by using `setx` to add the d: drive to path. Works like a charm. Many thanks for explaining this to me.